Axios vulnerability detected when installing @nuxtjs/auth-next
I have a nuxt project and I was trying to install nuxt auth but every time I install this package, it appears this Axios Cross-Site Request Forgery Vulnerability. This is my package.json file:
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^7.4.47",
    "@nuxtjs/auth-next": "^5.0.0-1667386184.dfbbb54",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "nuxt": "^3.10.3",
    "vue": "^3.4.21",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.71.1",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.3",
    "vuetify": "^3.5.9"
  }
}

I have searched online for a way to fix and I found out that a solution for this problem is to install an axios version >= 1.6.0. So I installed the latest axios version but the problem persists. I checked if the version installed is above or equal to 1.6.0 and it is in the package.json file and by entering the following command: npm list. I also tried to install in a different computer and I deleted the package-lock.json and the node_modules folder and then installing again all dependencies but both approaches did not work. Also I tried to run the command npm audit fix --force but it did not work. What am I missing?

NPM audit report refers to this vulnerability.
The correct command to list nested axios dependencies is npm list axios. It shows that both @nuxtjs/auth-next and @nuxtjs/axios have dependencies on Axios 0.x:
+-- @nuxtjs/auth-next@5.0.0-1667386184.dfbbb54
| +-- @nuxtjs/axios@5.13.6
| | `-- axios@0.21.4
| `-- axios@0.26.1
+-- axios@1.6.8
`-- nuxt@3.11.2
  `-- @nuxt/devtools@1.1.5
    `-- @vue/devtools-applet@7.0.25
      `-- @vue/devtools-ui@7.0.25
        `-- @vueuse/integrations@10.9.0
          `-- axios@1.6.8 deduped

The intention is to dedupe nested axios dependencies to project's axios@1.6.8.
This requires to add overrides section to package.json:
  "overrides": {
    "@nuxtjs/auth-next": {
      "axios": "$axios",
      "@nuxtjs/axios": {
        "axios": "$axios"
      }
    }
  }

And completely reinstall the dependencies by removing package-lock.json and node_modules and running npm i. The outcome is that the output of npm list axios should be:
+-- @nuxtjs/auth-next@5.0.0-1667386184.dfbbb54 overridden
| +-- @nuxtjs/axios@5.13.6 overridden
| | `-- axios@1.6.8 deduped <--
| `-- axios@1.6.8 deduped <--
+-- axios@1.6.8
`-- nuxt@3.11.2
  `-- @nuxt/devtools@1.1.5
    `-- @vue/devtools-applet@7.0.25
      `-- @vue/devtools-ui@7.0.25
        `-- @vueuse/integrations@10.9.0
          `-- axios@1.6.8 deduped

Overriding the dependencies with incompatible version contains a certain risk. Whether doing this won't have negative impact on the work of the package still needs to be verified.

Thank you! I did what you told and it worked.

The overrides worked great for my case (being told during build that the axios dependency was missing). One thing to note: you may have to do the clean build without the overrides in the package.json depending on the version of npm  you're using. You should be okay to just do the build but then just add the overrides back in once you're ready to build/run.
